# Will msmtp fallback to unencrypted connections if encrypted connections fail?

Tags: security, ssl, starttls, msmtp

My `~/.msmtprc` config file says to connect to a server on `port 25` with `tls on` and `tls_starttls on`. Is there a risk that, if the encrypted connection setup fails for some reason, then `msmtp` will fallback to a plaintext connection, possibly divulging the authentication passwords or email contents?

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: this is just my best guess, not a security guarantee.** From a quick look at the `msmtp.c` file in the source https://git.marlam.de/gitweb/?p=msmtp.git;a=summary it looks like the `msmtp_rmqs` function and other relevant functions, in the case where `HAVE_TLS` is set and the account is configured to use TLS and STARTTLS, will indeed fail when there is an error setting up the encrypted connection, instead of retrying without encryption.